# Using 3 updates in the same Store Procedure? "Small Error"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have the following SP, its has 3 update statements in it. Each I EXEC this SP i get an error  "Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_Rating_Comments, Line 41
Invalid object name 'RatingLines'.". This error is located in the second update statement. When I hide the second and The Third update statement my code works just fine. Any idea how can I use those 3 Update statements together.

```html
Alter PROCEDURE [HRSDB].[sp_Rating_Comments] 
-- @BookingNr varchar(25)
-- ,@Company varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
     ;WITH RatingLines AS   -- Get the important columns from both HRSDB tables
    (
   Select   RDA.[CTS]    AS [CTS]
     ,RDA.[B_KEY]    AS [B_KEY]
     ,RDA.[H_KEY]    AS [H_KEY]
     ,RDA.[RT_ID]    AS [RT_ID]
     ,RDA.[RT_AVGRATING] AS [RT_AVGRATING]
        ,RDDA.[RTD_COMMENT] AS [RTD_COMMENT]
                      
  From  [DynNavHRS].[HRSDB].[HTL_RATING_ALL_DA]        RDA
  Join  [DynNavHRS].[HRSDB].[HTL_RATING_DETAIL_ALL_DA] RDDA
  ON    RDA.RT_ID =RDDA.RT_ID
     AND   RDDA.[RTD_COMMENT] <> ''
     AND   RDA.[B_KEY]='19214642'  -- Just to test with one rec 
    )
    
-- First Table:  
  UPDATE     [DynNavHRS].[dbo].[HRS$Agency Header]
  SET        [Booking Rating] = '1'
  FROM       [DynNavHRS].[dbo].[HRS$Agency Header] AH
  INNER JOIN RatingLines   RL1
  ON         RL1.[B_KEY] = AH.[Reservation No_]
  WHERE      RL1.[RTD_COMMENT] <> ''   -- If the Booking have a comment in DB2
  AND        [Booking Rating] = '0' ;  -- in order to avoide scanning all line
 
-- Second Table: 
  UPDATE     [DynNavHRS].[dbo].[HRS$Correction Agency Header] 
  SET        [Booking Rating] = '1'
  FROM       [DynNavHRS].[dbo].[HRS$Correction Agency Header] CL
  INNER JOIN RatingLines   RL2
  ON         RL2.[B_KEY] = CL.[Reservation No_]
  WHERE      RL2.[RTD_COMMENT] <> ''   -- If the Booking have a comment in DB2
  AND        [Booking Rating] = '0'  ; -- in order to avoide scanning all line

-- Third Table:  
  UPDATE     [DynNavHRS].[dbo].[HRS$Agency Display Line] 
  SET        [Booking Rating] = '1'
  FROM       [DynNavHRS].[dbo].[HRS$Agency Display Line] DL
  INNER JOIN RatingLines   RL3
  ON         RL3.[B_KEY] = DL.[Reservation No_]
  WHERE      RL3.[RTD_COMMENT] <> ''   -- If the Booking have a comment in DB2
  AND        [Booking Rating] = '0'   ;-- in order to avoide scanning all line

COMMIT
END
```

Comment: Which dbms? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: probably you need to prepend DB name prior to ratingLines table.

Comment: You mean Microsoft SQL Server 2008?

Comment: @SMA Rating Line is coming from the ";with" its not a real table. I tried to do what you said then I received this error  "Invalid object name 'DynNavHRS.HRSDB.RatingLines'."

Comment: @ jarlh yes this is what I mean

Comment: The final statement in your SP is `COMMIT`, yet I never see a statement that begins the transaction (ie `BEGIN TRANSACTION`)

Comment: @ TT: I Added begin Transaction to my code, still Iam getting the same error. As I said If I took out the 2nd and the third update it will work. but I need to exec all updates together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start the SP with `;WITH RatingLines ...` which connects to the first `UPDATE` statement, not the other ones. This construct creates a CTE that is only visible to the first statement that follows it. More explanation can be found in the TN for [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx). In particular this excerpt from Remarks highlights this:

> A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, MERGE, or DELETE statement that references some or all the CTE columns.

To have this table known for all statements in your SP, create a table variable or a temporary table for the `RatingLines` instead.

Outline using a temporary table would be as follows:

```
Select   RDA.[CTS]        AS [CTS]
              ,RDA.[B_KEY]        AS [B_KEY]
              ,RDA.[H_KEY]        AS [H_KEY]
              ,RDA.[RT_ID]        AS [RT_ID]
              ,RDA.[RT_AVGRATING] AS [RT_AVGRATING]
              ,RDDA.[RTD_COMMENT] AS [RTD_COMMENT]
INTO #RatingLines -- Create #RatingLines as temporary table
From  [DynNavHRS].[HRSDB].[HTL_RATING_ALL_DA]        RDA
Join  [DynNavHRS].[HRSDB].[HTL_RATING_DETAIL_ALL_DA] RDDA
ON    RDA.RT_ID =RDDA.RT_ID
AND   RDDA.[RTD_COMMENT] <> ''
AND   RDA.[B_KEY]='19214642';

-- Throughout the rest of the SP, use #RatingLines as your ratings table; eg:
...
INNER JOIN #RatingLines   RL1
...

-- At the end of the SP, drop the temporary table
DROP TABLE #RatingLines;
```