# How to run SQL Server CTE more than once?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a CTE Query as given below

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT EmpId, EmpName, RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY EmpId)
   FROM Employeetemp
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

But I am getting issues in it as I can run either Select Query or Delete Query.

My second question is "What is CTE" ?  Is it an object, view or anything else.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The CTE disappears when the SELECT is done. Create a view instead.

Comment: To quote from my [own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29625635/243373) to a similar question: `A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, MERGE, or DELETE statement that references some or all the CTE columns.`. For more details see the MS technet article on [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in SQL Server with a single query.  Instead, one method to do what you want uses a temporary table:

```
SELECT EmpId, EmpName,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY EmpId)
INTO #EmployeeTemp
FROM Employeetemp;

SELECT * FROM Employeetemp;

DELETE FROM Employeetemp
    WHERE EmpId IN (SELECT EmpId FROM #Employeetemp WHERE RN > 1);
```

Comment: The only question is: Does the OP expect the CTE works as a temp table or like a view ?